# Unable to DM a bot in Slack. Bot was created with azure botframework and channel integration was used

Tags: azure, botframework, slack, slack-api

I have developed a bot with the help of Bot framework. I integrated it with Channels like Teams and Slack. Everything works file except one thing in slack.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-connect-slack?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=abs

I am able to add this bot as an app in slack but the are to enter text is grayed our with following message
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

> Sending messages to this app has been turned off.

I have tried various settings in Event subscription but nothing works. App metion in channels works fine.

Any advise.

Answer (score 2):

Just figured it out.

Go to your App Settings page and go to App Home and set the checkbox for "Allow users to send Slash commands and messages from the messages tab"

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/bot-docs/issues/2077#issuecomment-843960695

Comment: Once the setting is updated, quit and reopen Slack.

Comment: You saved my life thank you both